# onClick validation error while going to another activity

Tags: validation, button, onclick, charsequence

i am quite new to android programming and i can't figure out what is the problem here. 
i have a registration form that validates before sending register info and going to another activity. Form validate is working if false, but when all fields are entered there is and error when i click button.

Java code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class registracijaLastnika extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etName;
EditText etSurname;
EditText etPasswordL;
EditText etUsernameL;
EditText etEmailL;
EditText etRepeatPasswordL;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registracija_lastnika);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIme);
    etSurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPriimek);
    etPasswordL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordL);
    etUsernameL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsernameL);
    etEmailL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailL);
    etRepeatPasswordL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRepeatPasswordL);
    final Button bRegisterL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegisterL);
    bRegisterL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String type = "regLas";
            String ime = etName.getText().toString();
            String priimek = etSurname.getText().toString();
            String uporabnisko_ime = etUsernameL.getText().toString();
            String geslo = etPasswordL.getText().toString();
            String email = etEmailL.getText().toString();



            validate();
            if(!validate()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Signup has     Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new     BackgroundWorker(getApplicationContext());
                backgroundWorker.execute(type, ime, priimek,   uporabnisko_ime, geslo, email);
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(registracijaLastnika.this, registracijaKavarne.class);
                registracijaLastnika.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }

        }
    });}
 public boolean validate(){
    boolean valid = true;
    if(etName.length()<1 || etName.length()>32){
        etName.setError("Please enter valid name");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etSurname.length()<1 || etSurname.length()>32){
        etSurname.setError("Please enter valid name");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etEmailL.length()<1 || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher((CharSequence)   etEmailL).matches()){
        etEmailL.setError("Please enter valid email address");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etPasswordL.length()<1){
        etPasswordL.setError("Please enter valid password");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etRepeatPasswordL.length()<1){
        etRepeatPasswordL.setError("Please enter valid password");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!etRepeatPasswordL.equals(etPasswordL)){
        etPasswordL.setError("Passwords don't match!");
        valid = false;
    }
    if(etUsernameL.length()<1 || etUsernameL.length()>32){
        etUsernameL.setError("Please enter valid name");
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
}
```

XML file of this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_registracija_lastnika"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.lipic.coffeeaddict.registracijaLastnika">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/personal_information"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tNaslov2L"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tNaslovL"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etUsernameL"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPriimek"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etEmailL"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etRepeatPasswordL"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPriimek"
    android:hint="@string/Surname"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etIme"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etRepeatPasswordL"
    android:hint="@string/Rpassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPasswordL"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/proceed_to_caffeteria_information"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bRegisterL"
    android:onClick="regLas"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etIme"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:hint="@string/Name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tNaslov2L"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPasswordL"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUsernameL"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/owner_registration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tNaslovL"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

BackgroundWorker code:

```
private String backgroundRegLas(String regLasURL, String... params){

    try {
        String ime = params[1];
        String priimek = params[2];
        String uporabnisko_ime = params[3];
        String geslo = params[4];
        String email = params[5];
        URL url = new URL(regLasURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("ime","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(ime,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("priimek","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(priimek,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("uporabnisko_ime","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(uporabnisko_ime,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("geslo","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(geslo,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();

        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
        String result= bufferedReader.readLine();
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        return result;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

and here is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.lipic.coffeeaddict, PID: 3234
              java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
                  at com.example.lipic.coffeeaddict.registracijaLastnika.validate(registracijaLastnika.java:76)
                  at  com.example.lipic.coffeeaddict.registracijaLastnika$1.onClick(registracijaLastnika.java:53)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Application terminated.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in validate method

```
if(etName.length()<1 || etName.length()>32){
    etName.setError("Please enter valid name");
    valid = false;
}
```

Here you should have done

```
etName.getText().length()
```

Review all other if condition in validate method and change.